# Correct login with Doorkeeper/Bcrypt for Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, rails-api, doorkeeper, bcrypt-ruby

I have a created and API using rails 4 and at the moment I'm trying to figure out how to do the login. Since the API will be used for an iPhone app we decided to go with token authentication and Doorkeeper/OAuth2 gem.

So far I created a signin controller to take care of authenticating the user (I'm using bcrypt to hash passwords).

```
def create

  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:username])
  dbPasswordHash = BCrypt::Password.new(@user.password_digest)

  if @user == nil 
     render json: 'noUser', status: :unprocessable_entity
  else
    if dbPasswordHash == params[:password]

      client = OAuth2::Client.new(app_id, secret, :site => "http://localhost:3000/")

      access_token = client.password.get_token(@user.email, dbPasswordHash)

      render json: access_token.to_json, status: :ok, location: @user

    else
      render json: {status:'ERROR',status_info:'Wrong username/password'}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end      
  end
end
```

The problem I'm having with the above code is that Faraday timesout. The issue lies with the access_token call. Since a POST request was made to /signin the second one (access_token), which goes to Doorkeeper to authenticate, will have to wait until the first is done.

I'm not sure if I'm over complicating the process but what I want to achieve is for a request to be made from the front-end, the user is authenticated and token's returned to the front-end for future use.

Another approach I tried is to POST to /oauth/token with:

{
  "grant_type"    : "password",
  "username"      : "test@gmail.com",
  "password"      : "$2a$10$igmaaZkrSviHc.8Glm3hcuRdqzeT5YQwYaKFN9eUbpfcmCqA3PBiO",
  "client_id"     : "f5cbc8d91f6e007c003e17baf3f45cb83cede4313c381afa99e456f59b08e3f8",
  "client_secret" : "f827f84548b33ebd8042cfbaa7aff944f5844aad7962623ed68d83963bc62bb5"
}

This approach works fine but the password is already hashed and when I try to use

```
    dbPasswordHash = BCrypt::Password.new(params[:password])
```

in doorkeeper.rb I get an error about BCrypt (I did try "require 'bcrypt'").

Any suggestions would be welcomed.